# How can I change the background color inside the icon?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an icon and I would like to change the background color inside the shape of the icon:

```
<i class="icon-sm icon-number-one"></i>
```

This is the css:

```
.icon-sm {
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'icons';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #949494 !important;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.icon-number-one:before {
    content: "\e600";
}
```

The icon looks like a circle with a number in it. Based on this how can I change the background color of the circle?

Comment: can you add your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: What libraries are you using? I made a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lerq82ea/2/) and it just shows nothing without text inside. Also it won't load for me(the link).

Comment: David check the comment above this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need effect look like this

[image]

then you only need

```
.icon-sm {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: Yes I know , I was just wondering if you could change the color inside the phone icon (see above link) somehow?

Comment: @bierhier No, but if it's a circle you can put `border-radius: 50%` on the element to clip the background color to a circle shape.

Comment: @bierhier ok i understand your question now, but i think it's impossible for irregular shapes. only for circle or square